# What is meaning and significance of inequality column in missing index stats?

Tags: sql-server, index

What is meaning and significance of inequality column in missing index stats?

I'm trying to understand how does it influence the way dba will create an index?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Columns would be listed in the `inequality_columns` if the query prompting the missing index request has a range predicate, such as `>` or `NOT`.  [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-details-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says this about the `inequality_columns` column in `sys.dm_db_missing_index_details`:

> Comma-separated list of columns that contribute to inequality predicates, for example, predicates of the form:
>
> table.column > constant_value
>
> Any comparison operator other than "=" expresses inequality.

Here is an example, using the StackOverflow Core Database:

```
USE StackOverflowCore;

SELECT TOP(100) v.PostId
    , v.BountyAmount
FROM dbo.Votes v
WHERE v.BountyAmount > 100
ORDER BY v.BountyAmount DESC;
```

The query plan for this query looks like:

[image]

The missing index request is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Votes] ([BountyAmount])
INCLUDE ([PostId])
```

Looking at the missing index DMVs, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_missing_index_columns(mig.index_handle) mic
```

| index_group_handle | index_handle | column_id | column_name | column_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | BountyAmount | INEQUALITY |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | PostId | INCLUDE |

As you can see, the `BountyAmount` is included in the `column_usage` column as an `INEQUALITY` column, since we're asking for values greater than a specific amount.

Adding an equality predicate to the `WHERE` clause, as in:

```
SELECT TOP(100) v.PostId
    , v.BountyAmount
FROM dbo.Votes v
WHERE v.BountyAmount > 100
    AND v.UserId = 1000  /*  THIS IS NEW */
ORDER BY v.BountyAmount DESC;
```

Results in the missing index query results showing the following:

| index_group_handle | index_handle | column_id | column_name | column_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | UserId | EQUALITY |
| 5 | 4 | 4 | BountyAmount | INEQUALITY |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | PostId | INCLUDE |

As you can see, the `UserId` column is now showing up with an `EQUALITY` indicator, and the resulting missing index looks like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Votes] ([UserId],[BountyAmount])
INCLUDE ([PostId])
```

The takeaway here is that the `INEQUALITY` key columns in an index should typically be listed after the `EQUALITY` key columns.

Answer (score 3):

### predicates

Equality columns:

- `=`
- `IS NULL`
- `INTERSECT`
- `EXCEPT`

Inequality columns:

- `>=`
- `<=`
- `>`
- `<`
- `!=` and `<>`
- `IS NOT NULL`
- `BETWEEN`
- `LIKE`

Comment: Here's a missing index hint, which claims `INTERSECT` is an equality https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=b5d3f47667f40a48d3f40dd7d049463a. If you think about what these two operators do, even though they work on whole sets in the query, they actually function as semi- and anti-joins with all columns being equality predicates. The only difference between `SELECT x FROM t1 INTERSECT SELECT y FROM t2` and `SELECT x FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.x=t2.y)` is how they deal with nulls.

Comment: I suppose one can get the same missing index hint with JOINs as well.